# Vue JS: Accessing data from different component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that has a 'vue-webcam' component inside, my problem is how can I access the "stream" inside of it data and set it to stop using my method out side of that 'vue-webcam' component. Is there anyway of or I have to make a state

```
<script>
  export default{
    components:{
      'vue-webcam':{
        render:function(h){
          return h('video',{
            ...
          })
        }
        props:{
          ...
        },
        data:{
          return{
            video: '',
            stream: '', // I need to get this using my btn_stop 
            hasUserMedia: ''
          }
        }
      }
    },
    data:()=>({
      ///...
    }),
    methods:{
      btn_stop(){
        let tracks = this.stream.getTracks()[0] // How do I access the "stream" data above on my vue-webcam component
        tracks.stop()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: create a boolean `isPlaying: true` in your parent component's data, pass it to `vue-webcam` as a prop. in `btn_stop()`, set `isPlaying` to false, and now your `vue-webcam` can handle the tracks by watching `isPlaying`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component methods are available publicly. You can set a `ref` property for your component and call methods on it. For example, add a `stop` method to `vue-webcam`...

```
methods: {
  stop () {
    this.stream.getTracks()[0].stop()
    this.$emit('stopped') // for extra points
  }
}
```

then in your parent component's template

```
<vue-webcam ref="webcam" @stopped="someOptionalEventHandler" .../>
```

and in the `btn_stop` method...

```
methods: {
  btn_stop () {
    this.$refs.webcam.stop()
  }
}
```

---

While you're here, Vue component `data` **must** always be a function and preferably not an arrow function (especially if you need to refer to component instance properties). So both your `data` properties above should be

```
data () {
  return {
    // data properties
  }
}
```

or

```
data: function() {
  return {
    // data properties
  }
}
```